# Paypal IPN Broadcast to multiple websites

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've been trying to find a solution for this for months but i couldn't...

Paypal only allows me to put one IPN address, but i need more than one for my membership sites to work and other scripts.

How can the Paypal IPN message be broadcast to multiple locations instantly?

Please tell me in a newbie way.

Thanks!

Comment: only thing i can think of is to capture all `$_POST` variables, then within the one IPN.php file, send out to each other IPN file u want by use of curl.

Comment: I use this service: https://ipnforwarder.com/ so then I can change the notify url when ever i want (and also can send the ipn to multiple urls)

Answer (score 0):

How are you processing paypal payments?

With PayPal Payments Standard, you can supply a different notify_url for each membership site that will be used as the IPN endpoint for those transactions' notification.

Comment: i use PayPal Payments Pro, but can the button have multiple notify-url? can you show me an example on how to use it? like <input type="hidden" notify_url="www.site1.com/ghfhg-ipn" notify_url="www.site2.com/75675-ipn" />